# recursive checking between 2 numbers

Tags: c

I got a task for hw to make a recursive function that checks between 2 unsigned long long numbers and check for common digits if there is its will print the common digits (its starts checking from right to left- when a match found we stop and print that digit)
if there is no same digits its will return -1

````
The problem is I could make it work for the first and last example but I am having trouble dealing with the second example.
any hints will be appreciated :)

```c
int findCommonDigit(unsigned long long n1, unsigned long long n2) {

    int temp1 = 0, temp2 = 0;
    if (n1 == 0 || n2 == 0)
        return -1;
    temp1 = n1 % 10;
    temp2 = n2 % 10;
    if (temp1 == temp2)
        return temp1;
    return findCommonDigit(n1 / 10, n2 / 10);

}
````

Comment: Does "common digit" mean that it is in the same position in both numbers? If so then example 2 should return -1.

Comment: @interjay they just need to have the same digit in the number no matter their position (but we check from right to left )

Comment: If the digits are in different positions then "right to left" isn't enough information (for example, should 12, 21 return 1 or 2?). Also, in that case the first example should return 4.

Comment: Also in the case of the third example it should be 9 even if the position of digits is significant or not.

Comment: @interjay i have fixed the first example
about your question.that's tricky one tbh
if n1 = 12 then i guess 2 should be returned if n1 = 21 then 1 should be returned.

Comment: Are you supposed to return the "number" of common digits, or "the" common digits? Example 3 looks like the "5" is the "number" of common digits. Example two looks like "the" digit.

Comment: @akm what do you mean? 9 possibilities ? yeah but we print what is the most right which is 5

Comment: @Tyler the  common digit its self should be returned

Comment: " we print what is the most right which is 5" <- That information is not in your question. You should edit your question and add that information.

Comment: @Tyler i have mentioned that we check the numbers from right to left. 5 is the rightest

Comment: Not to be too pedantic, but "(its starts checking from right to left)" doesn't mention to stop when a match if found.

Comment: @Tyler well i guess tell that to my proffesors, this is pretty much how to got the question also .

Comment: Urgh, I thought there were two threads on this. Turns out I was looking at the name of one of the answerers, lol. If you _do_ have classmates struggling with this, tho... I took a lot of time to help your mind(s). Share the wealth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the task, as I understand it, is to determine whether or not two numbers share at least one digit. Constraints are:

- Scan right to left.
- In the case of (21, 12) return 1, not 2. (As per your commentary.)
- The solution should be a recursive function.

Right-O. So, the trick is to compare every digit in the first number with every digit in the second number. There are quite a few ways to optimize this, but we will stick with an O(n²) brute-force method.

Given `123` and `456`:

- compare `3` with `6`
- compare `3` with `5`
- compare `3` with `4`
- compare `2` with `6`
- compare `2` with `5`
- compare `2` with `4`
- compare `1` with `6`
- compare `1` with `5`
- compare `1` with `4`

Hopefully you can see that that was a nested loop:

```
for each digit in N1:
  for each digit in N2:
    match?
```

Conveniently, getting the rightmost (“least-significant”) digit value is a simple remainder operation:

```
int digit = number % 10;
```

After that we modify the number to shift all the digit places down one using integer division:

```
number = number / 10;
```

We want to use *recursion* (instead of a *looping* construct like `while` or `for`), so we need to transform each one of those loops into a recursive function call.

### Basic Recursion

A recursive function works by having one or more termination conditions. Failing the termination condition, it just calls itself with updated arguments.

For simple example, we can take a counting loop:

```
void print_START_to_STOP( int start, int stop )
{
  for (;  start < stop;  start = start+1)
    printf( "%d\n", start );
}
```

And make it recursive:

```
void print_START_to_STOP( int start, int stop )
{
  if (!(start < stop)) return;           // termination condition
  printf( "%d\n", start );               // (loop body)
  print_START_to_STOP( start+1, stop );  // invoke next iteration
}
```

Take a few minutes to convince yourself that those two functions are equivalent. One uses an explicit loop. One uses recursion.

### Inner Loop

Let’s start easy and work on a recursive function for the inner loop:

```
bool isDigitInNumber( int digit, unsigned long long number )
{
  ...
}
```

As recursion needs at least one termination condition, the first thing to check is if there are any digits left in `number` to check against the argument `digit`. If not, there is no match.

```
  if (number == 0) return false;
```

The next thing to do is check to see if the least-significant digit of `number` matches the `digit`. If it does, we have another termination condition:

```
  if ((number % 10) == digit) return true;
```

Otherwise we are left needing to check the remaining digits in `number`. This is where we invoke recursion:

```
  return isDigitInNumber( digit, number/10 );
```

### Zero?

You might ask, “What if `digit` is `0` and `number` has a `0` in it?”
Give it a try. Does it work for `number` == `201`?

“Okay, so what if `digit` is `0` and `number` is *also* `0`?”
*That* is a good question. Should `findCommonDigit( 0, 0 )` return `0` or `-1`?

(Chances are your professor expects `findCommonDigit( 0, 0 )` to return `-1`. I personally think it would be more correct if it returned `0`. The only thing that *shouldn’t* return `0` is if either one of the numbers does not have an embedded zero, such as `123` and `456`, and `0` and `123`.)

Let’s come back to this in a minute.

### Reflection

Let’s think about what we’ve done to simplify our problem:

- `isDigitInNumber( 3, 456 )`
- `isDigitInNumber( 2, 456 )`
- `isDigitInNumber( 1, 456 )`

If any one of those is true, then we can return the matching digit. Otherwise we return `-1`.

You should also notice that there is still an outer loop to conquer.

### Outer Loop

For the outer loop, we can create a new recursive function that makes use of the last recursive function.

Take a second and think about what this recursion is looping over: `N1`.
Just as the last function loops over `N2` and gets the digit-to-compare by using remainder on `N2`, *this* recursive function loops over `N1` and gets the digit-to-compare by using remainder on `N1`:

```
int digit_to_compare = n1 % 10;
```

Again we need some termination conditions and a recursion.

When do we stop and return `-1`?
(After looping through all digits of `N1` and not finding a match using `isDigitInNumber()`.)
So... when `N1` is zero we are done. No match. Return `-1`.

```
  if (n1 == 0) return -1;
```

Otherwise we need to try to match the digit-to-compare with all the digits in `N2`:

```
  if (isDigitInNumber( digit_to_compare, n2 )) return digit_to_compare;
```

And finally, the digit wasn’t matched, we need to recurse on the next digit in `N1`:

```
  return findCommonDigit( ... );
```

You are basically done.

### Zero Redux

Now back to that tricky question about zeros.

Remember that the inner-loop algorithm *could not* check for the possibility of zero matching zero. But that’s okay. It wasn’t the right place to check.

The right place is before you do any loops at all. Right at the beginning of your algorithm, check to see if `N1` == `N2`. If it does, then the rightmost digit of both numbers is the same. Even if both numbers are zero.

```
int findCommonDigit( ... )
{
  if (n1 == n2) return (n1 % 10);  // return the matching digit, which might be 0
  return findCommonDigit_Impl( n1, n2 );
}
```

You will have had to rename the last `findCommonDigit()` function to `findCommonDigit_Impl()`, of course.

### So many functions! What the double-hockeysticks?!

In order to handle the special condition of zeros we had to add yet *another* function to the mix.

That is kind of unavoidable. Otherwise we can’t tell the difference between `findCommonDigit( 123, 0 )` and `findCommonDigit( 0, 0 )`, and the result differs between `( 123, 0 )` and `( 0, 123 )`.

Anyway, we now have have *three* functions:

```
bool isDigitInNumber( int digit, unsigned long long number );
int findCommonDigit_Impl( unsigned long long n1, unsigned long long n2 );
int findCommonDigit( unsigned long long n1, unsigned long long n2 );
```

The last one is the one that gets invoked by the user:

```
int main(void)
{
  printf( "%d\n", findCommonDigit( 1234, 2 ) );
```

The other two are the recursive functions, and do not get invoked by the user.

**It is entirely possible to combine these all into a *single* recursive function.**

Don’t waste your time though. Doing that increases complexity, and you would have to add additional formal arguments to deal with it. (Or use global variables or some other Don’t-Do-That-Crufty hack.)

It is entirely okay to have useful helper functions. And when dealing with recursion, this kind of multiple-function structure is actually very common and normal.

Hopefully this wasn’t too long-winded, nor gave away the answer too easily. Much of the time spent here was to help think your way through designing a recursive algorithm, so that when you have to do it again in the future you won’t be utterly lost. (Recursion is hard!)

AAAANNNND, hopefully your classmates will get it too, but without producing an exact copy of you code, lol. Professors want you to learn, not cheat off the internet, and I’ve made this fairly easy to draw that kind of conclusion, alas.

### P.S

BTW, you might get away with using a loop inside your recursive function: an explicit inner loop for the digits of `N2` and recursion for the outer loop over `N1`. IDK if that is acceptable. This answer assumes no loops allowed.

Comment: Actually this is the best answer from my point of view. I think it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I made a mistake in the testing for zeros code. (I just wrote myself my own answer using the advice I gave here, just to make sure I don’t lead y’all astray, and found it.) In the final function, we _also_ need to check both whether either `n1` or `n2` equal zero. If so, run `isDigitInNumber()` directly (with the non-zero number as second argument) to determine whether or not to return `0` or `-1`. Heh, always test. (I should learn to do that before posting... maybe someday...)

Comment: @Dúthomhas That's what drew me into software development so many years ago... The irrepressible optimism of its practitioners, a.k.a. the rose-colored glasses used by most when reading their own code (mea culpa!!!) Fantastic answer you've posted, deserving many more UV's.

Comment: i just spoke with my proffesor and he told me that i should take in mind that the input number are  natural bigger then 0, so zero doesnt matter anymore?
i still didnt take deep reading but will right away

Comment: Us armchair helpers at home will always modify requirements to fit our interests. Fortunately for your own work, though, your professor has basically just told you "your code will never get `0` as an input number", so yeah, you don't have to care about that edge case. Just the two recursive functions will do. :O)

Comment: if (isDigitInNumber( digit_to_compare, n2 )) return digit_to_compare;
can you please explain this line? i got a bit confused here

Comment: Everything has a _type_ (both a hard data type like `int` or `struct point` or `const char *` and a conceptual type like _**age**_ or _**position**_ or _**surname**_). What type of thing is `findCommonDigit()` supposed to return? How does that differ from what `isDigitInNumber()` returns?

Comment: one of them suppose to return int and one might return long long ? sorry i really lost you  here,
I understand about data types but in recursion i am bit confused about what returns.
if i would guess this if statement should return 0 / 1

Comment: Yes, a truthy _boolean_ value: true IFF a digit value appears in a number. (Make sure to `#include <stdbool.h>` so you can use `bool`, `true`, and `false`.) However the `findCommonDigit()` function returns a _digit value_, not just a yes/no answer. So if the digit is found in the inner loop (you get a “true” from `isDigitInNumber()`) then you can end the outer function (`findCommonDigit()`) by returning the digit that was found. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a while loop until "n2 > 0" in main function. For every digit you will call "findCommonDigit" function and check is the return value is -1 or not. If you get a digit that is not -1 then print it and break the While loop. After the while loop you can write printf("-1").
For that you have to change this  `return findCommonDigit(n1 / 10, n2 / 10);` to this `return findCommonDigit(n1 / 10, n2);`

Otherwise you can change your function to this,

```
int findCommonDigit(unsigned long long n1, unsigned long long n2) {
    int temp1 = 0, temp2 = 0;
    if (n1 == 0 || n2 == 0){
        return -1;
    }
    temp1 = n1 % 10;
    temp2 = n2 % 10;
    if (temp1 == temp2){
        return temp1;
    }
    n1 /= 10;
    return findCommonDigit(n1, n2);
    n2 /= 10;
    return findCommonDigit(n1, n2);
}
```

Comment: I am kinda confused.
while loop in recursive function? i was always told that i should avoid using that

Comment: No you have to write the while loop in "main" function.

Comment: No while loops needed, but this is a fun tricky problem. Gimme about an hour to get back to my PC and I'll post something you may find usefil

Comment: Actually no WHILE loop is needed. You can do it by like this
```int findCommonDigit(unsigned long long n1, unsigned long long n2) {
    int temp1 = 0, temp2 = 0;
    if (n1 == 0 || n2 == 0){
        return -1;
    }
    temp1 = n1 % 10;
    temp2 = n2 % 10;
    if (temp1 == temp2){
        return temp1;
 }
 n1 /= 10;
    return findCommonDigit(n1, n2);
    n2 /= 10;
    return findCommonDigit(n1, n2);
}
```
call the recur function two times it will do the work. (checkout the edited answer)

Comment: the only thing i think about is if n1 = 2 and n2 = 1456245
n1 / 10 = 0 and then returns -1, so i am curious how to works
but really thanks for the example of code

Comment: I can think of a few numbers this will fail for.

Comment: @Duthomhas can you give me an example for what it can fail?
i will take a deep read in your explanation above

Comment: Same as in **Tyler**'s answer: his code has the same design flaw.

Answer (score 0):

##### You can use a loop based function instead like following:

```c
int findCommonDigit(unsigned long long n1, unsigned long long n2) {
    int digitN1[11] = {0}, digitN2[11] = {0};
    while(n1) {
        int x = n1 % 10;
        n1 /= 10;
        digitN1[x] = 1;
    }
    while(n2) {
        int x = n2 % 10;
        n2 /= 10;
        digitN2[x] = 1;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        if(digitN1[i] && digitN2[i]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Here `digitN1` and `digitN2` are two flag arrays used to store whether digits[0..9] are set on numbers `n1` and `n2` respectively. Then we use a for loop to check whether any digit is on both numbers or not. If no common digits found, -1 is returned.

Comment: i am having trouble to understand if its recursive or not

Comment: @secret1 you should mention in the question that you want a function that uses a recursive algorithm to solve the problem.

Comment: its actually mentioned in the title :)

Comment: ...and in the question text, both explicitly and in the example code.

Comment: @secret1 thanks for pointing it, I did not understand the problem constraint properly.

Comment: Writing recursive functions is hard. But it is _so_ worth what you learn. Learning to think this way makes you a _much_ better programmer than people who skip it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with based on your and my test cases.

Twice the recursion twice the fun!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEBUG_FUNCTION 0

int compareN1Digits(unsigned long long n1, unsigned long long n2)
{
    int n1RightDigit = n1 % 10;
    if(DEBUG_FUNCTION) printf("    n1 right most digit : %d\n", n1RightDigit);
    
    int result = -1;
    if (n1RightDigit != n2)
    {
        if(DEBUG_FUNCTION) printf("Not a match.\n");
        if (n1 > 10)
        {
            result = compareN1Digits(n1 / 10, n2);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result = n1RightDigit;
    }
    
    return result;
}

int findCommonDigit(unsigned long long n1, unsigned long long n2)
{
    int n2RightDigit = n2 % 10;
    if(DEBUG_FUNCTION) printf("n2 right most digit : %d\n", n2RightDigit);
    
    int result = -1;

    result = compareN1Digits(n1, n2 % 10);

    if (result == -1)
    {
        if (n2 >= 10)
        {
            result = findCommonDigit(n1, n2 / 10);
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}

void RunTestCase(unsigned long long n1, unsigned long long n2, int expectedResult)
{
    int result;
    
    result = findCommonDigit(n1, n2);
    if (result == expectedResult)
    {
        printf("Corrent Result\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Result NOT corrent!\n\n");
    }
}
    
int main()
{
    // Test Case 1
    // 22222446, 113355578889 => function will give back -1
    RunTestCase(22222446, 113355578889, -1);

    // Test Case 2
    // 13259438, 2 => function will give back 2
    RunTestCase(13259438, 2, 2);

    // Test Case 3
    // 112233445, 112233445 => function will give back 5.
    RunTestCase(112233445, 112233445, 5);
    
    // Test Case 4
    // 2, 13259438 => function will give back 2
    RunTestCase(2, 13259438, 2);

    // Test Case 5
    // 12034, 567809 => function will give back 0
    RunTestCase(12034, 567809, 0);
    
    // Test Case 6
    // 1, 1 => function will give back 1
    RunTestCase(1, 1, 1);
    
    // Test Case 7
    // 0, 0 => function will give back 0
    RunTestCase(0, 0, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `findCommonDigit( 2, 13259438 )` • Also: warning C4715: 'findCommonDigit': not all control paths return a value.